# Python input not working on remote interpreter

Tags: python

The input function seems not to work on a remote python interpreter when I tried to input from keyboards in the console.

```
a = input('Input:')
```

The console won't allow keyboard typing and shows "this view is read-only". Is there any work around?

On my local interpreter it shows the below. You could enter after the ">?"

```
a = input('Input:')
Input:>?
```

But the remote one will just show:

```
a = input('Input:')
Input:
```

I'm using pycharm 2019.2 professional version and python 3.5.3

Thanks!

Comment: This depends entirely on what you mean by "remote python intepreter".

Comment: @chepner It's a VM on cloud end.

Comment: Aaaaand your particular interface to that VM is what exactly…?

Comment: @deceze Sorry, I don't quite get it. If you mean AMI system, it's on debian linux 9. Also I'm using pycharm 2019.2 professional version and python 3.5.3

Comment: The thing is, just it being remote has very little to do with anything. Properly set up, you could have a fully interactive remote interpreter. So it depends on the details of how this is set up here…